# Get-ADComputer in powershell fails with "Identity property on the argument is null or empty" error

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have a powershell script that makes a to call `Get-ADComputer`, at which point I get this error:

> Get-ADComputer : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The
>   Identity property on the argument is null or empty.

Here is the script:

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\computersforscript.txt

    foreach($line in $computers)

 {
    Get-ADComputer -Identity $line -Properties * | FT Name, LastLogonDate, MemberOf -Autosize

}

 $computers |
 Select-Object Name,LastLogonDate,MemberOf |
 Export-CSV -Path C:\Users\output.txt -NoTypeInformation

The script does iterate through each workstation on "computersforscript.txt
" but it does not export it and it errors out.
```

I appreciate if you could help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there are empty lines in the file.

You can have a check for `NullOrEmpty` as well as trimming white spaces.

```
foreach($line in $computers){
  if(-not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($Line)){
      Get-ADComputer -Identity $line.Trim() -Properties * | FT Name, LastLogonDate, MemberOf -Autosize
   }
}
```